# Java - Sanitizing user input in SQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-injection, checkmarx

We are scanning our Java project using [Checkmarx](https://checkmarx.com/) and it is flagging a violation under SQL Injection which says:

> The application's getClientConfigParameter method executes an SQL
> query with executeQuery, at line 56 of
> src/.../database/GSSGalaxyDBMain.java. The application constructs this
> SQL query by embedding an untrusted string into the query without
> proper sanitization. The concatenated string is submitted to the
> database, where it is parsed and executed accordingly. An attacker
> would be able to inject arbitrary syntax and data into the SQL query,
> by crafting a malicious payload and providing it via the input args;
> this input is then read by the main method at line 99 of
> src/gssgalaxy/ia/main/INStartApplication.java. This input then flows
> through the code, into a query and to the database server - without
> sanitization. This may enable an SQL Injection attack.

for below code block

```java
processid = dataloader.updateOnProcessTable(connection, prop.getProperty("ProcessTable"));
```

where we are getting the property from properties file and not from the users directly. And when this process id is injected to the SQL statement it shows it as a violation. We doubt it to be a false positive as there is no raw input being directly passed from the user input. We are looking for the ways to get rid of this violation.

**Edit - 1**
We have this prepared statemtent already in place, but for table names we are using something like this:

```
String query;
        String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT PROCESS_ID FROM ${table}";
        query = SQL_SELECT.replaceAll(TABLE_REGEX, processTable);

        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            processId = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        processId++;
        String SQL_UPDATE = "Update ${table} SET PROCESS_ID=?";
        query = SQL_UPDATE.replaceAll(TABLE_REGEX, processTable);
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, processId);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
```

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` for that

Comment: @Antoniossss, we are already using PreparedStatement, kindly check the edited question

Comment: And mentioned lines 56 and 99 are......